# Name formatting with cleveref - question about types

Tags: formatting, cross-referencing, cleveref

I want to customize the text that appears when I do a `\cref{}`, so for example, I want to make a link to section 0.1 but I want the text to say 'Summary' not section 0.1. I had this part working with the following line at the top of my document:

```
\crefformat{section}{\textbf{#2Summary#3}}
```

and then when I call the reference I use:

```
\cref{sec:CogSysParadigm}
```

And it shows up as Summary (but with a red box around it). Which is perfect. **My problem is that I can't get the same thing to work for an item.** I tried 'item', itemize item, subitem, etc. Example of what I tried:

```
\crefformat{item}{#2ToC#3} % so this would have a ToC as the text
```

and then I am using `\cref` like:

```
\cref{itm:CogSysParadigm} % but it gives me item 1(d)ii instead
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Probably `\crefformat{enumi}{#2ToC#3}` solves the problem?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why you need to modify the format of the references in this way, but I think that changing

```
\crefformat{item}{#2ToC#3}
```

to

```
\crefformat{enumi}{#2ToC#3}
```

is what you need.

For example, the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefformat{enumi}{#2ToC#3}
\crefformat{section}{\textbf{#2Summary#3}}

\begin{document}

\section{introduction}\label{sec:CogSysParadigm}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item 1.1
    \item 1.2
    \item 1.3
    \item
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item 1.4.1
      \item 1.4.2\label{itm:CogSysParadigm}
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
  \item 2
\end{enumerate}

In the \cref{sec:CogSysParadigm} I want to point out the \cref{itm:CogSysParadigm}.

\end{document}
```

produces:

[image]

Note that the first argument of `\crefformat` must be a counter and `enumi`, `enumii` and `enumiii` are the counters used by the `enumerate` environment for the first three levels.

Also note that this solution works at any level inside the `enumerate` environment. If you want it to work only at the third level you have to change `enumi` to `enumiii`.